# Spring boot doesn't start with annotation @SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I migrated my project from Spring boot 1.1.7 to 1.2.1 in order to use @SpringBootApplication.

In my class used to start the Spring boot server I replaced 3 annotations:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "uk.co.company")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

by

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

And since I did that the server does not start, I get an exception about Dependency Injection (BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: ...)

Do you know why?

Comment: Why do you have `uk.co.company` in the `@ComponentScan`? I suspect the class you have `@SpringBootApplication` on is in a subpackage of that.

Comment: Yes it is in a subpackage, so I see what you mean... I put the class with @SpringBootApplication at the top level and the components scan works fine. Thanks!